# Unable to connect to SQL Server from Excel to generate reports. Named pipes and tcp/ip are enabled. using trusted connection

Tags: sql-server

Trying to connect to SQL Server from Excel by using >>Data tab, >>From other sources >> from SQL server. It came back with the attached message
I made sure named pipes and TCP/IP are enabled in the SQL server configuration manager. It works on my laptop. But my friend is trying to install in her laptop and it is not working. Appreciate any ideas you can share with us. We are doing Developer Edition, custom install of the database server. Double checked the instance name and made sure remote connection is allowed.

This is the error message I get

> Unable to connect:
> We encountered an error when trying to connect.
> Details : Microsoft SQL: A network-related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL-SERVER. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify if the instance name is correct and SQL server is configured to allow remote connections. (Provided:Named Pipes Provider,error:40 Could not open a connection to SQL Server.

Comment: Firewall settings? If you're using a named instance you need udp/1434 open for SSRP (SQL Server Resolution Protocol) as implemented by SQL Browser Service. This is in addition to whichever port SQL Server itself is configured to listen on, e.g.: tcp/1433 is normally used for the default .\MSSQLSERVER instance. If you're using Named Pipes instead of TCP you need several more ports open: udp/137, udp/138, tcp/139 and tcp/445. Note: a default install of Developer Edition has the TCP/IP protocol disabled in SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager > Server Protocols.

Comment: Also: if you change any settings in SQL Server (version) Configuration Manager > Server Protocols you need to restart the SQL Server and SQL Browser services for the changes to be applied.